# Implementation example for Repository pattern with Linq to Sql and C#

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am looking for a Repository pattern implementation example/resource that follows domain driven design principles for my ASP.net MVC application. Does anyone have a good example or learning resource that can be shared?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not an uncontroversial implementation, but Rob Conery's web storefront project has implemented repository via Linq to Sql in C#.

http://blog.wekeroad.com/

Source is available.

He's not quite doing strict DDD, but his TDD is generally sending him out in that direction. The one caveat is that he has multiple repositories with no aggregate roots, so it's far from a textbook example. Also, earlier implementations of the repository returned IQueryable, so there were no domain boundaries on the repository, which is the source of most of the noise made about his design.

Answer (score 1):

Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans is a great place to learn all about the Repository pattern and more. http://dddcommunity.org/books/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article describing an implementation of the repository pattern using Linq to SQL. The full code is open source, available @ github.

http://www.macskeptic.com/living/by/the/code/c/2009/07/02/the-repository-pattern/

Comment: Very nice. I've downloaded the code and browsed through it. Very impressive and robust solution. Thank you.

Comment: Link appears to be broken. "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)"

Comment: Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/MACSkeptic/linq-to-sql-template-repository

Comment: The updated blog link is at http://www.macskeptic.com/living/by/the/code/c/2009/07/02/the-repository-pattern/

Comment: The links are dead :(